# Virtual environment keeps getting deleted on VertexAI in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nvidia, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have created a Managed Notebook on VertexAI using Nvidia's Merlin NGC. Then I created a virtual environment **"dl4coders"** work where I installed libraries FastAI, etc. However, every time I shut down and restart the notebook, my virtual environments are gone. Any idea why is this happening?

In the picture below, you can see that **dl4coders** kernel is appearing in the list.
[image]

However, the whole environment is deleted from the backend.

[image]

Question is why my virtual environment keeps getting deleted automatically?

Comment: Hi, do you have steps to make an virtual environment? I also believe this is intended as part of the resource management of managed notebook. Is there a way to save virual environment files to a certain directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Managed Notebooks are container based:

- JupyterLab server is a container
- Each kernel is a container

My guess is that your venv is created inside any of those containers and getting deleted upon restart since containers are ephemeral. Can you try creating the venv in /home/jupyter. Example:

```
virtualenv /home/jupyter/env
```

`/home/jupyter` is a mount which its contents are preserved upon restart.

Comment: While the contents of a venv are preserved, I have found that the kernelspec for the environment vaporizes, so the environment doesn't end up in the Launcher or the drop-down shown by the OP. While it should be easy enough, I haven't been able to sort out how get a post-startup script to re-expose kernels of existing environments, even when placing the kernelspec files in a valid location on the data (not boot) disk. (thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74921748/expose-kernel-for-existing-environment-on-vertex-ai-user-managed-notebook-startu))